# How can I dynamically create a VM with ansible?

Tags: virtual-machines, ansible

I know you can provision existing VM's with ansible playbooks, however I don't know if it is possible to create the VM as well.

How can I dynamically create a VM with ansible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ansible supports [a lot](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/list_of_cloud_modules.html) of different virtualization providers, both local and remote. Their documentation contains good examples of usage for each.

Answer (score -1):

There is also nothing stopping you from calling virsh/virt-install via `command`, and using ansible to create your XML config, disk images, etc.

Something a little like you might do for managing virtual hosts on a webserver.

This does assume you can runs commands on the hypervisor, though.